# Adding object in Array in nested object with setState

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to know how to add an object in `datasets`,
I'm trying to add an object in array with using setState,
but It doesn't work at all .

my code is like this :

```js
 const [DataContext, setDataContext] = useState([
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    }, 
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    },
```

```js
  const addAxis = index =>  {
    let addAxis = [...DataContext];
    addAxis[index].datasets.push({ label: "", data: "", background: "" });

    setDataContext(addAxis);
  };
```

Comment: that's because spread operator creates a shallow copy. you need to create a deep copy and then update the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a deep copy to update the state:

```
const addAxis = index =>  {
  setDataContext(dataContext => dataContext.map((data, idx) => {
     return idx === index ? {
        ...data,
        datasets: [...data.datasets, { label: "", data: "", background: "" }]
     } : data
  })
};
```

Comment: This is the most efficient way to do this, props to @DrewReese. You can use a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) to clone deep.

Answer (score 1):

You need to deep copy DataContext.

```
const _copy = (value) => {
    let object;
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        object = [];
        value.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (typeof value[index] === 'object') {
                object[index] = _copy(value[index]);
            } else {
                object[index] = value[index];
            }
        });
    } else {
        object = {};
        for (let key in value) {
            if (typeof value[key] === 'object') {
                object[key] = _copy(value[key]);
            } else {
                object[key] = value[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return object;
};

const addAxis = index =>  {
    let addAxis = _copy(DataContext);
    addAxis[index].datasets.push({ label: "", data: "", background: "" });

    setDataContext(addAxis);
 };
```